# error reproducing stack() example in R

Tags: r, r-raster

When I try to reproduce the stack() example given in the raster reference manual, I get the following error:

```
R> fn <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
R> s <- stack(fn, fn)
Error in rep.int(names(x), lengths(x)) :
  unimplemented type 'NULL' in 'rep3'
```

or if I try:

```
R> fn <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
R> r <- raster(fn)
R> s <- stack(r, fn)
Error in as.list.default(x) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

Has anybody an idea?!

Comment: Works for me. What is the value assigned to `fn`? Perhaps try re-installing the `raster` package?

Comment: `fn` is pointing to the `/home/.../my_Rlibs/raster/external/test.grd`. I am using the raster package quite a lot, but usually work with bricks or rasters which work fine!

Comment: I don't know if you found an answer, but that error rings a bell for me.  I see it when the raster package isn't well loaded.  There is a `stack` function in base R which gives this error if run using `raster::stack` arguments.